# Contiditional WHERE with two joins on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to create an effective query but can't get it working.

Tables:
- one table containing types of objects
- one table containing objects

Conditions:
- there can be single objects of a type
- there can be child objects of a type
- parent and child objects don't need to be of the same type
- objects can be published
- types can be published
- the results should only get pulled from a specific pool of object IDs. So i need to add  `AND (o.id IN (1,2,3,4)`

I want a simple result list that shows how many types are published and the number of objects assigned to these types.

```
types  

id | title |  published   
---------------------
1   type1   1
2   type2   1
3   type3   1
4   type4   1
5   type5   1
6   type6   0
7   type7   1

objects 

id |title | type | parent | published
---------------------------------------
1   a       1       0       1
2   b       1       0       1
3   c       3       2       1
4   d       2       0       1
5   e       2       2       1
6   f       4       0       0
7   g       5       6       1
8   h       6       0       1
9   i       3       8       1
10  j       3       8       0
11  k       7       8       1
```

Results should be:
type1 (#2)  (two singles)
type2 (#2)  (one single + one child of id 2)
type3 (#3)  (one child of id 2 + one published child of id 8)
type4 (#0)  (one single not published)
type5 (#0)  (because it's parent id 6 is not published)
type6 (#0)  (because type6 is not published)

I tried this one (type publishing not included):

```
SELECT o.type, t.title, COUNT(t.id) AS cnt 
FROM types AS t 
LEFT JOIN objects AS o ON o.type = t.id 
LEFT JOIN objects AS o2 ON o.id = o2.parent 
WHERE o.published = 1 AND o2.published = 1
GROUP BY o.type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions in the `WHERE` clause negate the "outerness" of the left joins.

Move those conditions to the `ON` clauses. The `WHERE` clause can be dropped.

Also, reference columns from `t`, the driving table, and count non-NULL expressions from the outer joined tables.

That will allow the query to return zero counts.

I didn't fully delve into the specification, but it looks like we want to count matching rows from `o` and `o2`.

I think something like this will get a resultset consistent with one interpretation of the specification... child `o2` rows get counted under parent `o` type, regardless of the type on the child `o2` row.

This is not tested, and I'm not fully understanding the specification...

```
 SELECT t.id                        AS `type` 
      , t.title                     AS `title`
      , COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) 
      + COUNT(DISTINCT o2.id)       AS `cnt`

   -- , COUNT(DISTINCT o.id)        AS `cnt_o`
   -- , COUNT(DISTINCT o2.id)       AS `cnt_o2`

   FROM types t

   LEFT
   JOIN objects o
     ON o.type       = t.id 
    AND o.published  = 1
    AND o.parent     = 0
    AND t.published  = 1

   LEFT
   JOIN objects o2
     ON o2.parent    = o.id
    AND o2.published = 1

  GROUP
     BY t.id
      , t.title
```

---

Not clear in the spec...

Do child rows (from `o2`) get omitted from the count if the `type` on the `o2` row matches a row in `types` that is `published=0` ?

If we are "grouping" by `type` on the `o2` rows , then we'd need to something different,

**EDIT**

we could get the count from the parent and the child separately, in two separate SELECT, and then combine the two resultsets with a UNION ALL set operator, and then total up the counts.

something along these lines:

```
SELECT c.type
     , c.title
     , SUM(c.cnt) AS cnt
  FROM (
         SELECT t.id                   AS `type`
              , t.title                AS `title`
              , COUNT(o.id)            AS `cnt`
           FROM types t
           LEFT
           JOIN objects o
             ON o.type       = t.id
            AND o.published  = 1
            AND o.parent     = 0
            AND t.published  = 1
          GROUP
             BY t.id
              , t.title

          UNION ALL

         SELECT tc.id                  AS `type`
              , tc.title               AS `title`
              , COUNT(oc.id)           AS `cnt`
           FROM types tc
           JOIN objects oc
             ON oc.type       = t.id
            AND oc.published  = 1
            AND t.published   = 1
           JOIN objects op
             ON op.id         = oc.parent
            AND op.published  = 1
           JOIN types pt
             ON pt.id         = op.type
            AND pt.published  = 1
          GROUP
             BY tc.id
              , tc.title
        ) c
  GROUP
     BY c.type
      , c.title
```

again, untested, and without a full understanding of the spec.

the count of the parent `o` is straightforward.  we use an outer join, with `t` as the driving table, so we get all types, and can get zero counts.

the count of the child `oc`,  we can do inner joins.  since the previous SELECT is getting us all the types, missing rows in the second SELECT won't cause a problem.

note that we join the child `o2` rows by type, and then we join to parent (to make sure parent is published), and join to parent type (to check that type is published) ...

---

How do we distinguish "parent" rows, do we check `parent=0` ?

Is this a hierarchy, can a "child" also be the "parent" of another row ?

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Another way to think about it (maybe this was the approach of the OP query) ... we are counting rows from `o`, parents and children.  What's important is that the `type` is published type, and that `o` is published.

Additionally, *either*

`o` is not a child (i.e. there isn't a row in objects `op` that has an `id` value equal to `o.parent)

*or*

if `o` does have a parent row (a row in objects `op` with an `id` value equal to `o.parent`, the [parent `op` is published and the parent type is published.

We could approach it like this:

```
SELECT t.id                   AS `type`
     , t.title                AS `title`
     , COUNT(o.id)            AS `cnt`
  FROM types t

  LEFT
  JOIN objects o
    ON o.type       = t.id
   AND o.published  = 1
   AND t.published  = 1

  LEFT
  JOIN objects op
    ON op.id        = o.parent
  LEFT
  JOIN types pt
    ON pt.id        = op.type

 WHERE -- this not a child (there is no parent)
       op.id IS NULL
    OR -- parent is published and parent type is published
       ( op.published = 1 AND pt.published = 1 )

 GROUP
    BY t.id
     , t.title
```

Comment: Yes, if a child has a type that is unpublished, then that child should be omitted from the results. Same thing if a parent has a unpublished type, then the parent and all its children should be omitted.

Comment: No. A child cannot be a parent.

Comment: Thanks very much so far. I will check tomorrow if I can use one of the approaches.

Comment: My apologies for posting three different queries. That first one doesn't match the spec, it disregards the `type` on the child.  I think the third query more closely matches the original approach ... we are just counting rows from `o` with a published type.  The tricky part is the `OR` conditions in the WHERE clause ... either "o is not a child"  or "o is a child and its parent is published and parent type is published".

Comment: OK. I tested the followup solution. It seems to work. One thing i forgot to mention is that the results should only get pulled from a specific pool of object IDs. So i need to add  `AND (o.id IN (1,2,3,4)`. But when i add it to the last where the results don't work anymore. Any Idea?

Comment: @Mike:  I would add the condition on `o.id` to the `ON` clause of the join; not the `WHERE` clause.  If we add it to the `WHERE` clause, it will negate the outerness of the  LEFT JOIN.  (if we add it to the WHERE clause, we would need to also allow for a NULL value of o.id , and we would need to add parens ... `AND` has a higher order of precedence than `OR`,    ... `( a OR b ) AND ( x OR y )`